# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta sin Columnas con datos repetidos en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, subconsultas, consultar

estoy en blanco con respecto a una consulta que no logro concretar al 100.

Necesito hacer una consulta con respecto al movimiento de unos radios, la cuestión es que cuando hago la consulta me da ese radio con todos los movimientos anteriores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito solamente el ultimo movimiento que se le haya hecho.

Aqui mi script del SQL:

```
SELECT distinct ipi.[descripcion]
  ,ipid.numero_serie
  ,itm.descripcion


FROM [inv_producto_insumo] ipi
  inner join [inv_producto_insumo_detalle] ipid on ipi.id_producto_insumo = ipid.id_prod_insumo
  inner join [inv_movimiento_detalle] imd on ipi.id_producto_insumo = imd.id_prod_insumo
  inner join [inv_movimiento_encabezado] ime on imd.id_doc_insumo = ime.id_doc_insumo
  inner join [inv_tipo_movimiento] itm on ime.id_tipo_movimiento = itm.id_tipo_movimiento

  where ipi.id_producto_insumo = 36 and ipid.estado != 0 and ime.id_tipo_movimiento != 5
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar porfavor :(

Comment: Ordena decentemente por el id Y haz un Top 1 en la select

Comment: Buenas, puedes usar si tienes el id para hacer un top 1, como dice @Francisco el cual es el más fácil si no tienes un campo único puedes usar una combinación de campos, o en caso de a ver qué no se puede comparar como la descripción puedes usar PLsql para hacer casos y sacar el valor que toca.

Comment: Evidentemente usar el id inv_movimiento_encabezado si es un autoincremental

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver el modelo de datos es difícil, pero puede probar algo así:

SELECT **TOP 1**

```
 ipi.[descripcion]
  ,ipid.numero_serie
  ,itm.descripcion


FROM [inv_producto_insumo] ipi
  inner join [inv_producto_insumo_detalle] ipid on ipi.id_producto_insumo = ipid.id_prod_insumo
  inner join [inv_movimiento_detalle] imd on ipi.id_producto_insumo = imd.id_prod_insumo
  inner join [inv_movimiento_encabezado] ime on imd.id_doc_insumo = ime.id_doc_insumo
  inner join [inv_tipo_movimiento] itm on ime.id_tipo_movimiento = itm.id_tipo_movimiento

  where ipi.id_producto_insumo = 36 and ipid.estado != 0 and ime.id_tipo_movimiento != 5
```

**Order by ime.id_doc_insumo DESC**

Evidentemente usar el

> ime.id_doc_insumo

de *inv_movimiento_encabezado* si es un autoincremental sino usar una fecha o agregar un id autoincrimental a Tabla...etc

Una opción muy interesante es tener en la tabla de productos un id_doc_insumo que apunte al ultimo movimiento realizado con ese producto, pero esto ya es de nota , depende de la cantidad de movimientos que realices y la necesidad de optimizar esas consultas...etc